# actionscript 3 open XML in for loop

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, function, for-loop

I'm trying to call an XML File in a for loop. I'm using following codes:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    savefilelocation = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("puzzle.xml")
    var puzzleInput:XML = new XML;
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest(savefilelocation.name));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML1);
    PuzzleTitle = puzzleInput.Title;
}
function processXML1(event:Event) :void{
    puzzleInput = new XML(event.target.data);
    trace("puzzleInput: "+puzzleInput.data)
    trace(puzzleInput.name)
    trace(puzzleInput.url)
}
```

Normally in for loops, I can call other functions. However, in this code part, I cannot reach processXML1 function. Is there a point that I missed? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add error listener to loaders and check if it gets called.

Comment: I added: myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,IO_ERROR_PuzzlegameLoaderXML1)
But it didn't go to error function neither

Comment: Why do you use an URLLoader when you could open the file with a _FileStream_ object synchronously?

Comment: I'm trying to get Title attribute from XML File. I wrote PuzzleTitle=savefilelocation.Title but it's not getting that attribute. How can I get Tittle from xml without URLLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been trying what Larusso said and finally I got the attribute. Here is the correct way:

```
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(savefilelocation, FileMode.READ);
    var rawData:String = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
    fileStream.close();
    var out:XML = XML(rawData);
    PuzzleTitle = out.Title;
```

I've added these codes instead of URLLoader. Finally I got correct result. Thanks for helping.